How to skip unchanged scenes from a network camera from VLC
I am saving the video stream from an IP camera to movie.mp4. When replaying the mp4 file most of the time there is no action. I want to check only when there is an action, i.e. when the scenery changes. I have VLC, but can install any player.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have you done any research regarding this yourself, prior to asking here? If so, what have you learned and what have you tried? If not, please do that. You're probably looking to skip portions where there is no movement, as far as how others having this challenge might phrase the question themselves.
